# Django - Edit access only if logged in user is the user who added the item or if he is a superuser

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am working on a rental website project where users can create a login and add a listing. Now I want the edit access to be given to only the owners of those listing and superuser. I am able to set the edit access either to superuser or to the user, I am trying to figure out how to do both.

models.py

```
class Listing(models.Model):

    category = models.ForeignKey(
        'Category', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    listing_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=720)
    description = models.TextField()
    bedroom = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True,)
    bathroom = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True,)
    lease = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    image_url = models.URLField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    image_one = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    image_two = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.listing_name
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def edit_listing(request, listing_id):
    listing = get_object_or_404(Listing, pk=listing_id)

    if not request.user.is_superuser or request.user == listing.user:
        messages.error(
            request, 'Sorry, you dont have the permission to do that.')
        return redirect(reverse('home'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user == listing.user:
            form = ListingForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=listing)
            if form.is_valid:
                form.instance.user = request.user
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Successfully updated the listing')
                return redirect(reverse('listing_detail', args=[listing.id]))
            else:
                messages.error(
                    request, 'Failed to update. Please ensure the form is valid.')
    else:
        form = ListingForm(instance=listing)

    template = 'listings/edit_listing.html'
    context = {
        'listing': listing,
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, template, context)
```

Particularly this line in the views is what I'm trying to achieve

```
if not request.user.is_superuser or request.user == listing.user:
        messages.error(
            request, 'Sorry, you dont have the permission to do that.')
        return redirect(reverse('home'))
```

Comment: Add a bracket `not (request.user.is_superuser or request.user == listing.user)`. since `not` has higher precedence than `or` it was evaluated first, you can add brackets to solve precedence issues like this.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you, that worked. Thank you. I'm a beginner, is it wrong to enter than without brackets?

Comment: The thing is `not request.user.is_superuser or request.user == listing.user` basically means `(not request.user.is_superuser) or request.user == listing.user` i.e. the `not` is applied on `request.user.is_superuser` this is because `not` has _higher_ precedence than `or`. You should search a bit on operator precedence.

Comment: Than you so much

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat your comment should be an answer!

Comment: @JaapJorisVens the question is too much different compared to what the OP's problem actually was. They show their model, view, etc. but their problem is simply operator precedence, I do believe if the OP actually edits their question and asks why their code does not work as expected then there likely would be a _duplicate_ target for the question, so I simply commented. :)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat how is the question different? I added the views and models just to give a background and have highlighted the exact lines which had issues at the bottom. I searched the web and stackoverflow for an answer before posting this question. I agree I couldn't figure out that it was operator precedence that was the issue.

Comment: @VishalRaju the comment was not meant to offend you in anyway. Your question is different in the sense the title "Edit access only if logged in user is the user who added the item or if he is a superuser" and even the content does not hint much at the exact problem and might cause people with similar searches to end up here. A better title would have been something like `Why is the condition "not A or B" not working as expected` or something similar. Moving further the models and even much of the view was not needed in the question.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat No offense taken. I understand what you mean, I can edit that.